# Intellij deleting classpath entries when importing from Eclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make the switch from Eclipse to Intellij, but I can't get my project to import correctly. It's a massive OSGI project, with dozens of bundles. (Disclaimer: I'm an OSGI and Intellij noob.)

I set up Intellij's OSGI support, but after I click "synchronize dependencies", Intellij wipes out a bunch of entries from my .classpath files. Here's an example:

Entries deleted:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/sigar.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar"/>
...etc. (All entries from classpath are deleted.)
```

Entries added (only 2 were added):

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
```

Comment: How did you import the project into IntelliJ?

Comment: I used Intellij's "Import Project" wizard. I then selected Eclipse in the "Import project from external model" menu. (Btw, I'm using Intellij 12.1.1)

Comment: Have you selected create module files near .classpath files?

Comment: @lhuang I tried what you suggested, and the .classpath files did NOT get erased this time. However, Intellij still doesn't export the jars... I'm stumped.

Comment: @burnsy What do you mean by " Intellij still doesn't export the jars"?

Comment: @lhuang In Intellij, I open the Project Structure menu, and select one of my library modules, which are supposed to export dozens of jars each. Intellij lists no exports for any of them. Unsurprisingly, other packages are broken because of these missing references. I suspect that I'm missing something very simple...

Comment: @burnsy I got what you meant. You meant that the export check box is not checked the those JAR's. Right? I just had a try, it worked well. What kind of "Dependencies storage format" are you using? All JAR's are not exported? Or just some of them are not exported?